# How to store multiple images and remove individual image ID in a bitmap file (by C++/Python/Java)

Tags: image-processing, bitmap, pixel, bmp

An image is a matrix of pixels. Each pixel can be represented by 4 components: Red, Green, Blue and Alpha. Each component value can be from 0 to 255. An image could be up to 4K quality, i.e. 3840 × 2160 pixels.

Implement an image repository which is a single file that can store many images (with different size) at the same time. An image within the repository file can be identified by its unique ID (4 bytes long)

The program should be able to:

- Open/create a repository file
- Add/Update/Delete an image into/from the opened repository file.
- Extract an image out of the repository using its ID with complexity level less than O(N) - where N is the number of images within the repository.
- Quickly detects if we add the same image into the repository (2 images are the same if all their pixels at the same position are the same)

Here's the code to write image to bmp file.

```
void writeBMP(unsigned char **Matrix, int Matrix_dimension){
    FILE *out;
    int ii,jj;
    long pos = 1077;


    out = fopen("output.bmp","wb");


    // Image Signature
    unsigned char signature[2] = {'B','M'};
    fseek(out,0,0);
    fwrite(&signature,2,1,out);


    // Image file size
    uint32_t filesize = 54 + 4*256 + Matrix_dimension*Matrix_dimension;
    fseek(out,2,0);
    fwrite(&filesize,4,1,out);


    // Reserved
    uint32_t reserved = 0;
    fseek(out,6,0);
    fwrite(&reserved,4,1,out);


    // Offset
    uint32_t offset = 1078;
    fseek(out,10,0);
    fwrite(&offset,4,1,out);


   // Info header size
    uint32_t ihsize = 40;
    fseek(out,14,0);
    fwrite(&ihsize,4,1,out);


    // Image Width in pixels
    uint32_t width = (uint32_t) Matrix_dimension;
    fseek(out,18,0);
    fwrite(&width,4,1,out);


    // Image Height in pixels
    uint32_t height = (uint32_t) Matrix_dimension;
    fseek(out,22,0);
    fwrite(&height,4,1,out);


    // Number of planes
    uint16_t planes = 1;
    fseek(out,26,0);
    fwrite(&planes,2,1,out);


    // Color depth, BPP (bits per pixel)
    uint16_t bpp = 8;
    fseek(out,28,0);
    fwrite(&bpp,2,1,out);


    // Compression type
    uint32_t compression = 0;
    fseek(out,30,0);
    fwrite(&compression,4,1,out);


    // Image size in bytes
    uint32_t imagesize = (uint32_t) Matrix_dimension*Matrix_dimension;
    fseek(out,34,0);
    fwrite(&imagesize,4,1,out);


    // Xppm
    uint32_t xppm = 0;
    fseek(out,38,0);
    fwrite(&xppm,4,1,out);


    // Yppm
    uint32_t yppm = 0;
    fseek(out,42,0);
    fwrite(&yppm,4,1,out);


    // Number of color used (NCL)
    uint32_t colours = 256;
    fseek(out,46,0);
    fwrite(&colours,4,1,out);


    // Number of important color (NIC)
    // value = 0 means all colors important
    uint32_t impcolours = 0;
    fseek(out,50,0);
    fwrite(&impcolours,4,1,out);


    // Colour table
    unsigned char bmpcolourtable[1024];
    for(ii=0; ii < 1024; ii++){
        bmpcolourtable[ii] =  0;
    }
    jj=3;
    for(ii=0; ii < 255; ii++){
        bmpcolourtable[jj+1] =  ii+1;
        bmpcolourtable[jj+2] =  ii+1;
        bmpcolourtable[jj+3] =  ii+1;
        jj=jj+4;
    }


    fseek(out,54,0);
    fwrite(&bmpcolourtable,256,4,out);


    for(ii=0;ii<Matrix_dimension;ii++){
        for(jj=0;jj<Matrix_dimension;jj++){
            pos+= 1;
            fseek(out,pos,0);
            fwrite(&Matrix[ii][jj],(sizeof(unsigned char)),1,out);
        }
    }


    fflush(out);
    fclose(out);
}
```

Comment: I am quite confused by your question. Or is it 2 questions - one about a *"bitmap file repository"* (whatever that is) and another about hashing something? Then you present some code which looks like the header for writing a BMP file but actually does nothing. Please try to improve it so we can help you better. Thank you.

Comment: @MarkSetchell: I edited the post. You can ignore the hash table I mentioned before. It was my thoughts to remove the image based on its ID. All tasks are listed above. Please suggest me with explanation code.

Comment: Do you mean you want to store lots of images at various offsets inside a single file? Why would you want to do that? How will you remove/delete an image from the middle of a file? If you really really want to do put all images in one file, maybe consider using a database such as `sqlite` but I have yet to understand why you would to do even that. What is the bigger picture please?

Comment: it should be the request to find an image in a folder based on its name: IMG_000, IMG_001... It's only different that we use a file as a repository instead of a folder. This is a software quiz not related to my job but I want to understand more about software algorithm.